# How to avoid generated JavaScript string literal to contain spaces used for indentation?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suppose I have an HTML string literal template looking like this:

```
let tpl = 
  `<div>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
   </div>`;
```

Once compiled to javascript (es5), it becomes something like:

```
var tpl = "<div>\n    <h1>Hello World</h1>\n     </div>
```

Which takes up uncessary space in generated code. What can I do to make the generated code like this:

```
var tpl = "<div><h1>Hello World</h1></div>";
```

OR at least:

```
var tpl = "<div>" + "<h1>Hello World</h1>" + "</div>";
```

Without having to actually write this logic in my TypeScript source code?

Comment: You can't. Template strings preserve whitespace, according to the spec. If you want no whitespace, you'll have to write it that way or run a regex replace on the template string. Note that gzip compression should render it more or less a moot point anyway.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You might want to have a look at how react-jsx is compiled however, so that you can implement your own white-space stripping transpiler with similar input syntax.

Comment: @JaredSmith The regex replace would need to be run on the source file, not the string value.

Comment: @Bergi yes I should have specified.

Comment: If you're only worried about the extra space in the source, it would seem that gzipping the file is going to handle the bulk of the problem, especially if you have many of these.

Comment: Also keep in mind that removing the space characters actually alters the DOM structure (assuming that's the intent for this HTML). Maybe you want that, but it can produce undesired results. For example if you have adjacent `<span>FOO</span>` and `<span>BAR</span>` on separate lines, it will display as `FOO BAR`, but if the spaces between are removed, it'll be `FOOBAR`.

Comment: Thanks guys for your ideas, I guess I should just pipe the output files through a `gulp` or `grunt` task to remove white spaces given a `regex` rule.

Comment: Because I don't think `minification` or `obfuscation` alone will remove white spaces in string literals anyway

Answer (score 0):

Template string preserves white spaces. 
You need to write your string without the white spaces to begin with.

```
var tpl = `<div>
<h1>hello world</h1>
</div>`
```

UPDATE: You can use tagged string template if you want to:

```
function trimIndent(strings: TemplateStringsArray) {
  return str[0].split('\n').map(s => s.trim()).join('')
}

var tpl = trimIndent`<div>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>`
```

You can improve the function `trimIndent()` to meet your need.

Comment: This can be a work around, but it will make writing longer template string harder, writing the template with indentation helps to visually make sure the HTML tags are correctly enclosed

Answer (score -5):

```
tpl.replace(/\s/gm, "");
```

`"/\s/gm"` is a regular expression which says "for all whitespace, tabs and line breaks", the `String.prototype.replace` function uses the regex to match all whitespace and linebreaks and replaces them with nothing.

Comment: Your missing the point. He wants the typescript compiler to do this not in Javascript

Comment: Missing the point or not, it removes *all* space characters, which would be clearly the wrong thing to do.